# what we will use for pyspark to build projects?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to know, similar to **SBT** or **MAVEN** for SCALA, what we will use for pyspark to build projects?

Comment: are you going to deploy it on AWS EMR or on-premise?

Comment: @Bitswazsky on premise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `setup.py`. First of all you have to create python `egg`.

```sh
$ python setup.py bdist_egg
```

If you would like to deploy your python application using `spark-submit` you have to use `--py-files` flag.

```sh
$ spark-submit --py-files project.egg
```

If you are going to write any production code I highly recommend reading this blogpost: https://developerzen.com/best-practices-writing-production-grade-pyspark-jobs-cb688ac4d20f#.wg3iv4kie